# How to add a new tab to tab bar in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I am developing an android app in which I want to add a new tab on tab bar by clicking a button, like we do in browser. Please can anyone tell me how to do it??

[image: Image link is here]

Comment: It's hard to help without code or the names of the plugins you use. Eg: Do you use React Native Navigation or somthing else?

Comment: @Poptocrack i don't have any code. I new to react native. plz help me.

Comment: Basically what you are asking is : "

 - Hey, can you help me with my car's engine
 - Ok, let's have a look at it, show it to me.
 - Hu, I have no car"

If you are new to React Native, I suggest you take a look at https://snack.expo.io/ . There's plenty tutorials for the React native basics (1-2 Weeks). Once you've done some of them, you can start to build you own app.

Comment: yes.. i am using React native Navigation. but not sure how to add new tab on button click.

Comment: i have already checked but did not get a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear in the documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting

Example code

```
import { TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class RecentChatsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>List of recent chats</Text>
  }
}

class AllContactsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>List of all contacts</Text>
  }
}

const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
  All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-scrollable-headref). I suggest you to use nativebase to make it easier, because they can provide scrollable tab. Then place add button at the end of the scrollable tab. Here is the example of scrollable tab code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Tab, Tabs } from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabOne';
import Tab2 from './tabTwo';
​export default class TabsScrollableExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header hasTabs/>
        <Tabs renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab />}>
          <Tab heading="Tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab2">
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab3">
            <Tab3 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab4">
            <Tab4 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab5">
            <Tab5 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using native base library to add new tab in tab bar

you can click on 'Add Tab' button to add new tab

```
import { Container, ScrollableTab, Tab, Tabs, Text,  Button } from 'native-base';

state={ category:[]}

renderTabButton() { 
 this.setState({category: [...this.state.category, (<Tab heading="Add Category"> 
     <Text>Tab 1</Text>
     </Tab>)]})};
      
render() {
 return (
  <Container>
          
    <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
        {this.state.category}
    </Tabs>
          
    <Button
       onPress={this.renderTabButton.bind(this)}> 

     <Text> Add Tab</Text>

    </Button>

  </Container>
```